# Get a list of combinations , where the difference is X

Tags: .net

I have to write a code in python - where the :-

- 1st step is that the user inputs any 10 integers(+/-)
- 2nd step is that the user inputs any single integer - X

The output should be list of combinations from the 10 integers, where the difference of the combination is X.

For example :-

```
1st step - User enters ( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
2nd step - User enters ('2')

Output - (3,1) , (10,8) , (6,4) etc
```

Comment: where the (10,2) came from??

Comment: Sorry that was by mistake - I meant (10,8)

Comment: I have tried , but I failed on doing it... I want to see how to do it, as I have a complex question ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
>>> list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> res = [(x, y) for x in list for y in list if (x-y)==2]
>>> res
[(3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 3), (6, 4), (7, 5), (8, 6), (9, 7), (10, 8)]
>>>
```

Comment: The code should allow the user to enter the numbers, as it can be anything.

Comment: Well, mate, this is the main logic. You should already be able to get input from the user by now.

Comment: @learncode [Here](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/io.html) is a tutorial on input-output.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> filter(lambda k:True if abs(k[0]-k[1])==x else False, list(itertools.combinations(range(1,a+1), x)))
[(1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 8), (7, 9), (8, 10)]
```